# How to get the video quality info of the OTT application when Its under network throttled by webdriver.io script

Tags: python, android, node.js, webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm using webdriver.io to automate the OTT application on android platform. I also implemented some usecase like network throttle to check the application latency with low network bandwidth in the webdriver.io session itself. And now I want to validate the video playback quality and need to collect **'resolution', 'bit_rate', 'frame_rate', 'compression'**, details from the video playback session.

Can someone please help me that how can I achieve this within the webdriver.io session. I also have the scope to perform this on various platforms like IOS mobile,fireTv, and Apple Tv. Please how can I build this capability as generic function so that I can use it on different platform to get the vido quality metrics which is under network throttle.